# how to create a regular expression to be case insensitive? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

this is what i have so far, which seems to work so far for capturing most urls (from html source code). This is my first regular expression so im not sure what to do.

```
<a href="(?=((https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.\-\/~]+){2,6}))|<a href="(?=((\/)([\da-z\.\-\/~]+){2,6}))
```

But it fails to match this url: goo.gl/uLxP6Z
it captures up to the lowercase 'u' and then it stops.

Comment: Use a Regex object: `new Regex(/.../,'i')`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches uppercase and lowercase letters: `[A-Za-z]`

Up to you to use this regex pattern, or the flag modifier suggested by Kiran Shahi. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript RegExp i Modifier. Syntax is as follows:

```
new RegExp("regexp", "i")
```

or

```
/regexp/i
```